# Rsync, copy through symlink

Tags: backup, rsync, symlink

I am using rsync to backup my server to an offsite server. Due to diskspace on my backup server, I have created a couple of symlinks to put some of the data on a different drive. However, instead of copying through to that symlink location, rsync is deleting the symlink and replacing it with a real directory.

How can I get rysnc to copy through the symlink on the destination?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you're invoking rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the option `--no-implied-dirs`.

For more info, see `man rsync`.

Look at the paragraph that explains the usage of this option.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manpage, the `-l` flag to rsync:

```
-l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
```

should do what you want.